# AJAX in Sails : should we use a library or framework on top of Sails and express js?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, backbone.js, sails.js

Say the client posts a variable V, then the server app enters the new data in mongoDB, then (depending on the selected input form) the server may respond "you have successfully entered V" or after backend calculations may respond with the resulting variable R : "your answer is R".

The question is : in **Sails js** can we *safely* implement **AJAX** or AJAJ without the help of jQuery nor a node.js framework such as Backbone or Angular on top of Sails ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your POST requests using standard HTML forms:

[Sending and retrieving form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

If you are wanting to know how you send responses back to the client-side, sails comes with ejs (embedded JavaScript), which you can use to render your server responses:
[EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/)

By 'safely', I assume you mean securely?  Probably one thing you should be aware of is that sails uses 'blueprints' by default, which exposes certain CRUD operations, which you may not want exposed in production.  You should read the comments inside the blueprints.js file in the sails config folder.

```
  // `actions` are enabled by default, and can be OK for production-- however,
  // if you'd like to continue to use controller/action autorouting in a production deployment,
  // you must take great care not to inadvertently expose unsafe/unintentional controller logic
  // to GET requests.
```

You should build out whatever request handling you actually need inside your controllers.  Then you can disable the default actions.